# Previous Year Sales Calculation, SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR alternatives?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a customer dashboard that has 2 years worth of sales, purchases, and inventory data. However, the customer does everything by their Fiscal Calendar rather than calendar year. This caused me to have to make some initial tweaks but I created a fiscal calendar that I use as the master date calendar for the application. Once I created the necessary relationships, this seemed to solve it.

However, after updating the data with the most recent week, now I am getting strange results from my measure for previous year sales. The formula is as follows:
`PY Sales $ = CALCULATE(SUM('Weekly Sales by State'[Sales $ - TY]),SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Fiscal Calendar'[Date]))`

The formula is pulling one week behind from the previous year and the final fiscal week is now 5x larger than it should be.

[Fiscal Week Totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQw3m.png)

Date Dimension table for reference:

[Fiscal Calendar Table used as date dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xtCb.png)

Any thoughts on how I can tweak my PY Sales formula?

I have tried a few variations using EDATE but I still was not able to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something similar to the following with the understanding that it will have a minimum grain of fiscal week.

```
PY Sales $ = 
  SUMX(
    DISTINCT('Fiscal Calendar'[Fiscal_Yr]),
    (
      var prvYear = CALCULATE(MAX('Fiscal Calendar'[Fiscal_Yr])) - 1
      var fiscalWks = CALCULATETABLE(DISTINCT('Fiscal Calendar'[Fiscal_Wk]))
      return
        CALCULATE(
          SUM('Weekly Sales by State'[Sales $ - TY]),
          REMOVEFILTERS('Fiscal Calendar'),
          'Fiscal Calendar'[Fiscal_Yr] = prvYear &&
          'Fiscal Calendar'[Fiscal_Wk] IN fiscalWks
        )
    )
```